# how to type the beginning or end in sed multiple-lines mode?

Tags: sed

As we all knew,the "**\‘**" and "**\’**"

[image: img]

indicates the beginning or end respectively in multiple-lines mode.But under ASCII(or input-in-english) only "**'**" exists.
How to type the beginning?

Comment: I do not believe the statement _As we all knew_ is correct. Furthermore, could you give us an example how you want to use the front and back quotes as currently your question is not clear. You are mentioning something about multi-line mode ... for what kind of language?

Comment: backslash followed by backtick character matches start of string, not sure if that's what you meant

Comment: @Sundeep Thks a lot. That's it. The backtick. But it looks same in mine sed's documents, so Make me confused.

Comment: @Sundeep I've been using sed for 40 years and have never heard of ```\` ```, I've always used `^` to match the start of string. I just checked the POSIX sed spec and the GNU sed man page and couldn't find any reference to ```\` ``` but it did work as a replacement for `^` when using GNU sed in non-POSIX mode with ```echo 'foo' | sed 's/\`f//'``` (but not with `sed --posix ...`) - so it seems to be a GNU-ism but is it defined somewhere and what's the point of using it instead of `^`?

Comment: @EdMorton as far as I know, it is a GNU sed extension. When you use `m` flag, `^` and `$` anchors will match start and end of every line. So, in such a scenario if you also want to match start/end of string, you can use backslash followed by backtick/single-quote respectively. Regarding documentation on this, check `info sed` or online version (https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

Comment: Ah, I see there it says `There are special character sequences (\` and \') which always match the beginning or the end of the buffer.`. Interesting choice by the GNU folks to, when `m` is used, change the POSIX meaning of `^` and `$` from start/end of string to start/end of line and then invent ```\` ``` and ```\' ``` to mean what `^` and `$` normally mean instead of leaving `^` and `$` alone and defining ```\` ``` and ```\' ``` to mean start/end of line (or coming up with something else to mean start and end of line)! Anyway, TIL, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
seq 3 | sed -n 'p;H;1h;$!d;g;l0
                s/^.*$/ALL/mgp
                s/\`.*$/START/mp
                s/^.*\'\''/END/mp'
1
2
3
1\n2\n3$
ALL
ALL
ALL
START
ALL
ALL
START
ALL
END
```

The command `seq` generates a file of three consecutive integers.

The sed uses the `-n` option to turn off implicit printing and then slurps the three integers into hold space. Printing each integer as it is read.

The first substitution, replace all lines with the literal `ALL`.

The second substitution, replaces the first line with `START`.

The third substitution, replace the last line with `END`.

N.B. The use of the `m`(multiline), `g`(global) and `p`(print) substitution flags. Lastly, if the `-z` option is in use, these zero width anchors work with respect to null characters not newlines.